# Latitude and Longitude is getting null in Flutter (Get Current Location)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using this plugin `flutter_geofence` to get current location latitude and longitude. Below is the sample dart code, problem i facing is inside the `Geofence` body i can get latitude and longitude but when i try to access outside it is getting null.

```
return Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  var latitude;
                  var longitude;
                  Geofence.initialize();
                  Geofence.requestPermissions();
                  Geofence.getCurrentLocation().then((cd) {
                    latitude = cd!.latitude;
                    longitude = cd.longitude;
                  });
                  print(latitude); // getting null
                  print(longitude); // getting null
                },
                child: Center(child: Text('Test'))),
          ),
        );
```

> DataService.class

```
class DataService {
Future<List<RecommendedForYouData>?> makeRequestRecommendedForYou(
      BuildContext context) async {
var latitude;
var longitude;
Geofence.initialize();
                  Geofence.requestPermissions();
                  Geofence.getCurrentLocation().then((cd) {
                    latitude = cd!.latitude;
                    longitude = cd.longitude;
                  });
                  print(latitude); // getting null
                  print(longitude); // getting null
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem happend because your variables are outside the function (Geofence.getCurrentLocation().then ...), if you put this variables inside {} probably you can get different value than null, but I recommend create a new function outside the build method.

1. If you use a Stateful Widget:

- Declare your variables in the top of your class.
- Use initState and call your methods inside (Geofence.initialize(), Geofence.requestPermissions(), Geofence.getCurrentLocation())
- You can create a specific function outside the initState to call inside of your build method.
- Inside your specific functions you need call the setState function to rebuild your UI.

I recommend you use a state management like bloc or provider instead of setState.

Comment: And if it is not a StateFul or Stateless Widget it's a just a simple class then how to do this?

Comment: I also added some code which is in class

Comment: Your DataServices class can extend of "Change Notifier" and then you can inject this class in the top of your widget tree, to use her functions or variables in your widget. 

I recommend you use a provider state management (or other) but so you can inject this class in the top of your widget treen and then instance this DataService class and use her variables.